# multiline in subscript

Tags: math-mode

what is the correct way to write the following?

```
\begin{align}
&\prod_{\substack{p \leq x \\  $p$ ~{}odd }} p 
\end{align}
```

Any help would be appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: please always post a test document not a fragment but remove the `$` you are already in math mode

Comment: note you can mark up the code block by highlighting and using the `{}` button (I did it for you this time)

Comment: Something like `\prod_{\substack{p \leq x \\  p \text{ odd} }}` should do.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat remarkably similar to my answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is `odd`, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat you were actually first but you sneaked it in while I was writing some words

Answer (score 5):

[image]

you are in math mode so you don't want `$` around p, conversely you want to get out of math for `odd`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[
\prod_{\substack{p \leq x \\  p \textrm{ odd}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: many Thanks,sir.

Comment: I wasn't complaining (and did not plan to write an answer anyway). This was more like a plan B if the question gets closed so that the OP has something that works. (But since we are chatting: will `\textrm` be a good choice if the OP has `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` in the document?)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I wondered about that. If the "$p$ is odd" is just a sentence in english that;s positioned in the math it should pick up the surrounding text font (I'd claim) but if it's a defined term, the identifier of a particular subset of the natural numbers, then it's a math identifier and should be in a fixed `\mathrm{odd}` if it's a bit of both, hard to choose...

Comment: So your answer is wrong and you need `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}


\[
\prod_{\substack{p \leq x \\  p \in\mathds{Z}\setminus2\mathds{Z}}}
\]
\end{document}`? ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat my answers are never wrong, you must be confusing me with egreg

Answer (score 0):

The best answer for sure is that of very nice user @David Carlisle. I would just like to add the ability to create a specific macro that generates the same result. Obviously it is more uncomfortable than the usual command `\substack`: just I have put an idea.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\produ}[2]{\underset{\underset{\scriptstyle #2}{p\leq x}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[\produ{\prod}{p \text{ odd }}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]